# How to cast Array[Any] to Long datatype in spark scala to store data in scala model object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

i have a demo as scala model object.
and retrieving data from cassandra and storing in a dataframe.
i want to retrieve the value of a particular column and store it into scala model object.
But not able to do it, please help me to resolve this.

```
class demo
{
  var aid:java.lang.Long=null;
var a_name: String=null;


def  getaid(): java.lang.Long = {
        return aid;
    }
    def  setaid( assetId: java.lang.Long) {
        this.aid = assetId
    }

def  geta_name(): String = {
        return a_name;
    }
    def  seta_name( assetId: String) {
        this.a_name = assetId
    }

}
------------------------------------------------

object test_cassandra extends Context1{

def main(args : Array[String]) = {
println("Hello World")

// df_read1= dataframe data                      
                      //   println(df_read1.show) 


                    // println(df_read1.filter("id == 2").show)   

                         df_read1.createOrReplaceTempView("so_tags")
                        var res= sparkSession.sql(s"select * from so_tags where id=$in ")


                        //i get the datatype of ab as String
                        //var ab= res.select("name").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList.mkString

                        //below i get the datatype as  Array[Any] but i need Long datatype to insert into model object
                         val Tp0= res.select(res.col("s_id").cast("Long")).rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()

                        //For Below i get error like type mismatch; found : Array[Any] required: Long
                        demo.setaid(result.select("a_id"))

//how to cast  Array[Any]  to java.util.Date below
val Tp1= res.select(res.col("s_id").cast("Date")).rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
```

Comment: use asInstanceOf.

Comment: Thanks for response ajay..